# How do I pass a unique_ptr to another class for using only the methods of the pointer (not changing ownership)?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Which is the correct/good-practices to pass the `Derived` instance stored inside a `unique_ptr<Derived>` to another object that only uses the methods of the `Derived`, without changing ownership? I don't know if I'm making myself clear. I just want to use the `Derived` instance (call its methods and work with it) but keeping the ownership (hence prevent deleting resources by another object) by the method that created it.

Here's a little example to clarify it. It also includes inheritance because that's more like my real problem:

```
class Base
{
public:
    Base() : m_value(0) {}

    void doThings() { m_value = 1; }

protected:
    int m_value;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived () : m_value(0) {}

    void doThings() { m_value = 2; }
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();

    void run(Derived &instance) { m_ptr = &instance; callMethod(); } // Is this way correct?
    void run(const unique_ptr<Derived> &instance) { ¿Don't know exactly what to put here? callMethod(); } // Is this way correct?

    void callMethod() { m_ptr->doThings(); }

private:
    Derived *m_ptr;
    // Alternatives?
};

int main()
{
    // I want main to be the unique ownership of the ptr resources
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<Derived>();

    Foo foo();
    // I want to pass the pointer (or its contents) to work with it in another class
    foo.run(*ptr); // What should go here? ptr.get()?

}
```

Should I pass the `unique_ptr` in some way? const reference maybe? Or just pass a raw pointer to the resource?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with ownership, don't use smart pointers. Pass a reference (if you are certain object exists) or raw pointer (if it can be null).

Comment: But If I pass a raw pointer (through `m_ptr.get()` I suppose), if the receiver makes a `delete` is it allowed? And, what about the advices of not using raw pointers in modern c++? And the semantics inside the receiver function? I mean, the receiver doesn't know that it comes from a `unique_ptr` so he can try to do a `delete`. Is that correct?

Comment: It's not allowed to `delete` that pointer, you are correct. But it wouldn't be valid if you provided address of stack object either, so you need to know whether you received ownership of the raw pointer or not inside that function. Using raw pointers is a life-lasting debate, IMO it's perfectly fine if you never use `new` - therefore you never `delete` anything. It's entirely up to convention in your code - if you assume that raw pointer never carry an ownership (unless explicitly stated), then your code convention prevents you from `delete`ing things.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think is better to pass a reference to the object hence. And keep a raw pointer in the class to track it through the methods. Thank you.